# Maven Plug In for Eclipse that comes with ADT Bundle

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I need to run Maven  in the cmd line as follows:

**mvn clean install**

using a **pom.xml** file within a **locally cloned git repository** that is an **MQTT client**.

Specifically, the git repository is: **org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java**, within which the **pom.xml** exists.

This URL was used for the cloning of the above git repository:

**https://github.com/jacarrichan/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.**

**I need to use only an Maven Plug In for Eclipse, since most of the pom.xml files specify version numbers in the Eclipse plug in for various artifacts.

I cannot use a stand alone Maven downloaded and installed separately, or the Plug In which comes with Android Studio, for this reason.**

The problem now is that I am using the **Eclipse that comes with the ADT Bundle**, and it does not have **Help  Eclipse Market Places** menu option, and there seems to be no way to **Integrate Maven with the Eclipse that comes with the ADT Bundle.**

**Is there anyway to integrate Maven as a Plug In into the Eclipse that comes with the ADT Bundle?**

Thanks,
Jaisimha Narahari

Comment: You are talking about the [M2Eclipse (m2e) plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), right?

Comment: Yes. Any Maven Plug In for Eclipse should actually do. But it must be for the Eclipse Juno which comes in-built with Android ADT Bundle (Note: ADT Bundle, NOT ADT Plug In). The in-built Eclipse Juno in Android ADT Bundle differs from the regular Eclipse Juno available from eclipse.org. I have pointed out one difference in my Question.

Comment: I think that the answer is partly in the question itself. Since the in-built Eclipse Juno in Android ADT Bundle does not have options such as "Check for Updates" and "Eclipse Marketplace" required to install plugins for Eclipse, it implies that the ADT Bundle does not support Maven builds.                                                                                                The reason may be that Gradle is the new replacement build tool supported by Google.

Comment: I think that the answer is partly in the question itself. Since the in-built Eclipse Juno in Android ADT Bundle does not have options such as "Check for Updates" and "Eclipse Marketplace" required to install plugins for Eclipse, it implies that the in-built Eclipse Juno in the ADT Bundle does not support Maven builds.                                                                                                  In any case, I got the jar files I needed using the standalone maven download, but only after editing the pom.xml file, so all is well. So this question can be deleted.

Comment: Good to hear that you found an answer. Questions, and answers, if considered helpful aren't deleted on SO so that others can benefit from it in the future, as well. You can also answer your own question, and accept in later on, so that it doesn't appear as unanswered any more.